# Signals doesnt work in inserted on fly widgets

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

I have a custom widget, like button, which has next structure

```
GtkWidget* button_new(ServerEntity *server)
{
    GtkWidget *fixed;
    GtkWidget *favoriteEventBox;
    GtkWidget *eventBox;

    fixed=  gtk_fixed_new();
    eventBox = gtk_event_box_new();
    favoriteEventBox = gtk_event_box_new();

    gtk_fixed_put(GTK_FIXED(fixed), eventBox, 0,0);
    gtk_fixed_put(GTK_FIXED(fixed), favoriteEventBox, 183,8);

    g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (eventBox),
                    "button_press_event",
                    G_CALLBACK (on_event_box_button_press),
                    server);

    g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (favoriteEventBox),
                    "button_press_event",
                    G_CALLBACK (on_favorite_box_button_press),
                    server);

    g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (fixed),
                    "draw",
                    G_CALLBACK (on_fixed_draw),
                    server);

    return fixed;
}
```

I put it into vbox, then in scrollable window:

```
    GtkWidget *scroll_window;
    scroll_window = gtk_scrolled_window_new(NULL, NULL);
    box = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 5);
    gtk_scrolled_window_add_with_viewport (GTK_SCROLLED_WINDOW (scroll_window), box);
return scroll_window;
```

box remains visible in c file and I use it later to add widgets on fly. Host widget is single, so I can do that.

Then I put it into gtk_fixed, gtk_fixed and window

When I add my custom button during all widgets construction, it receives button-press on both nested boxes and draw signal. But when I add button later, only draw signal is invoked, only when I pull scrollbar.

This how I add buttons during construction and execution both.

```
void server_list_set_servers(SERVER_ENTITY_CONTAINER* servers)
{
    int servers_count = server_entity_container_get_items_count(servers);

    int j = 0;
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < servers_count; i++)
    {
          GtkWidget* button;
          ServerEntity* server = server_entity_container_get_item_at(servers, i);
          button = button_new(server);
          // gtk_table_attach_defaults (GTK_TABLE (table), button, j, j + 1, i, i  + 1);
          gtk_box_pack_end(GTK_BOX(box), button, TRUE, TRUE, 5);
          gtk_widget_show (button);
    }
}
```

And during-construction button still receives all signals, but next to it, added on fly - no.

Tried to connect "event" signal to everything, removed scrollable_window, changed box to table - doesn't work. Why this is happens?

Comment: I've seen a lot of examples about adding widget on fly, but noone uses signal system. I think point is that signals cannot be subscribed after main_loop called. That's why when I construct vbox and put button - it works, but when I put some more - they dont work. [signals](http://www.gtk.org/tutorial1.2/gtk_tut-18.html). So I am going to make extra window, which is constructing with pulled from server data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not understand half of the things you say so maybe I did not get your real problem but I know you can dynamically change the GUI, connected or not to signals, without any problem.

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static void
child_button(GtkButton *button)
{
    GtkWidget *dialog = gtk_message_dialog_new(NULL, GTK_DIALOG_DESTROY_WITH_PARENT,
                                               GTK_MESSAGE_INFO, GTK_BUTTONS_CLOSE,
                                               "A child button has been clicked");
    gtk_dialog_run(GTK_DIALOG(dialog));
    gtk_widget_destroy(dialog);
}

static void
main_button(GtkButton *button, GtkContainer *vbox)
{
    GtkWidget *widget = gtk_button_new_with_label("New button");
    g_signal_connect(widget, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(child_button), NULL);
    gtk_container_add(vbox, widget);
    gtk_widget_show(widget);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    GtkWidget *window, *vbox, *button;

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);

    vbox = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 6);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), vbox);

    button = gtk_button_new_with_label("Add button");
    g_signal_connect(button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(main_button), vbox);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(vbox), button);

    gtk_widget_show_all(window);
    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}
```

You can also prepare the widget (connected or not to the signal) and add it later, just reorder the code in the above snippet. Signals are just C callback after all.

### Addendum

I updated the above code to use `GtkEventBox` and `button-press-event` signals just to show that changing widget or signal does not change the final result.

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static gboolean
child_event_box(GtkEventBox *event_box)
{
    GtkWidget *dialog = gtk_message_dialog_new(NULL, GTK_DIALOG_DESTROY_WITH_PARENT,
                                               GTK_MESSAGE_INFO, GTK_BUTTONS_CLOSE,
                                               "A button has been pressed inside a child event box");
    gtk_dialog_run(GTK_DIALOG(dialog));
    gtk_widget_destroy(dialog);
    return FALSE;
}

static gboolean
main_event_box(GtkEventBox *event_box, GdkEvent *event, GtkContainer *vbox)
{
    GtkWidget *label = gtk_label_new("Dynamic event box");
    GtkWidget *widget = gtk_event_box_new();
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(widget), label);
    g_signal_connect(widget, "button-press-event", G_CALLBACK(child_event_box), NULL);
    gtk_container_add(vbox, widget);
    gtk_widget_show_all(widget);
    return FALSE;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    GtkWidget *window, *vbox, *label, *event_box;

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    vbox = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 6);
    event_box = gtk_event_box_new();
    label = gtk_label_new("Add event box");

    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), vbox);

    /* The default event mask for GtkEventBox already includes
     * GDK_BUTTON_PRESS_MASK but it is not documented.
     * Better to be safe than sorry...
     */
    gtk_widget_add_events(event_box, GDK_BUTTON_PRESS_MASK);

    g_signal_connect(event_box, "button-press-event", G_CALLBACK(main_event_box), vbox);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(event_box), label);

    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(vbox), event_box);

    gtk_widget_show_all(window);
    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is what I am talking about - a lot of examples how to add any widget and it will render properly - all good. But I add event_box dynamically and button-press event will never work, despite that graphically it took its place. That was my problem. I figured that signals are attached only before gtk_main, I can't attach one more like C# on the fly. Now I have two-windowed app and problem solved. Hope will help anybody else.

Comment: @al.kozachenko I wrote the above example exactly to show that the sentence _"signals are attached only before gtk_main"_ is false. `main_button` is called after `gtk_main` and handle signals flawlessly.

Answer (score -1):

GTK system cannot connect delegate-function to signal after main loop started.
So it is a good practice to recreate whole view as window.

In my case, I take credentials from user in login GtkWindow, call gtk_quit, make two requests to server - first validates creds, second grabs data, and only then I create Main GtkWindow with all data in hand, and populate it with any number of buttons as I want.

Comment: The sentence "GTK system cannot connect delegate-function to signal after main loop started" is false. Your real problem (whatever it is) is not this one. I just added to my answer an example with `GtkEventBox` and `button-press-event` signals that are attached **after** the main loop is started. I should add it is rather common to dynamically generate widgets and/or attach or change signals inside the main loop.

Comment: @ntd You are right, events are attaching after main loop, I see it. Tried with GtkScrollableWindow on your code - works too. Have idea why my code doesn't work? Will "add" procedure work if it has been called not by event-callback directly? Like http-engine responce delegate? App is single-threaded.

Comment: My wild guess is your `GtkEventBox`es have a 0x0 size, hence they do not receive any event. But I am a developer, not a soothsayer ;)